# Parsing Google Fusiontable API returned JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-fusion-tables

Can someone please shed some light on how to parse this JSON object returned by Google Fusion Tables query APIs in Javascript?

```
{
 "kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse",
 "columns": [
  "Name",
  "Function",
  "Culprit"
 ],
 "rows": [
  [
   "Bha3",
   "9, 41",
   "1"
  ],
  [
   "Bha23",
   "7, 26, 56, 57",
   "1"
  ]
 ]
}
```

I want to extract values Bha3 and Bha23 from this object. But there are no names in "columns" and "rows" objects. So essentially, this is not a JSON object(?) How do I get individual values from rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access those values by looking up the 2-d array `rows`

```
data.rows[0][0]; //Bha3
data.rows[1][0]; //Bha23
```

Where data is your object.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gjRDL/)**

And with simple for loop you can access all values like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/7S3Vp/)**

Comment: Thank you for the super fast response. This is almost a 'duh' moment for me, but perhaps this is not the day for my little grey cells to work. 

I changed my javascript to match your answer:
<quote>
var json = xmlHttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = json.rows[0][0] + "<br>";
</quote>

But this just prints blanks. If I instead only use json.rows, it prints as 'undefined' in the "response" field.

Comment: Do this,  `var json =  JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);` Because in your responsetext it is string you need to convert it to object, so u use `JSON.parse`

Comment: I missed the eval part.

var json = eval( "(" + xmlHttp.responseText + ")" );

Like I said, not my day today. Thanks much for help!